# How to run pytest from a python script subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

I need to run pytest test_start.py and keep running the program.

My cod:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['pytest', r'C:\Python\test_start.py'], shell=True)
print('hello')
```

But when I run the script, pytest starts executing and print waits for it to finish.
How can I run py test and go ahead to execute the script?

UPD: When i used subprocess.Popen - I see that print has been executed, but I don't see the execution of pytest

Comment: The `shell=True` isn't doing anything useful here; see also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess). Generally, running Python as a subprocess of itself is probably something to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.run` specifically waits for the process to finish.  If you don't want to wait, use `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: When I used Popen, I see that print has been executed, but I don't see the execution of pytest, the browser has not opened - how do I understand that something has started there?

Comment: When you use bare `Popen` you take on all the responsibilities that a higher-level function lke `run` perform on your behalf, including handling any input or output (with `communicate`) and waiting on the process (with `wait`). The [tag:subprocess] tag's [info page](/tags/subprocess/info) has links to a few common FAQs about this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply adding
time.sleep(5) after subprocess

```
subprocess.Popen(['pytest', r'E:\Parser\Python\test_start.py'], shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
print('hello')
```

Apparently pytest just didn't have time to start)

Comment: No, that's not how it works.  By the time `Popen` returns, the process is underway.  Now, if your code depends on the RESULT of the `pytest`, then you should be using `run` anyway.